# Problemas restando fechas en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo un problema un poco absurdo restando dos columnas en una tabla:

```html
atabase changed
MariaDB [registro]> SELECT batchnumber, L5enddate, L3beddate, (L5enddate-L3beddate) as Ciclo FROM batchinput;
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| batchnumber  | L5enddate  | L3beddate  | Ciclo     |
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| COL-01-01    | 2019-03-25 | 2019-03-09 |        16 |
| COL-01-02    | 2019-03-21 | 2019-03-10 |        11 |
| COL-01-03    | 2019-03-21 | 2019-03-11 |        10 |
| COL-01-04    | 2019-03-25 | 2019-03-12 |        13 |
| COL-01-05    | 2019-03-26 | 2019-03-13 |        13 |
| COL-01-06    | 2019-03-26 | 2019-03-14 |        12 |
| COL-01-07    | 2019-03-28 | 2019-03-15 |        13 |
| COL-01-08    | 2019-03-26 | 2019-03-16 |        10 |
| COL-01-09    | 2019-03-27 | 2019-03-17 |        10 |
| COL-01-10    | 2019-03-31 | 2019-03-18 |        13 |
| COL-01-11    | 2019-04-01 | 2019-03-19 |        82 |
| COL-01-12    | 2019-04-02 | 2019-03-20 |        82 |
| COL-01-13    | 2019-04-02 | 2019-03-21 |        81 |
| COL-01-14    | 2019-04-05 | 2019-03-22 |        83 |
| COL-01-15    | 2019-04-03 | 2019-03-23 |        80 |
| COL-01-16    | 2019-04-04 | 2019-03-24 |        80 |
| COL-01-17    | 2019-04-07 | 2019-03-25 |        82 |
| COL-01-18    | 2019-04-05 | 2019-03-26 |        79 |
| COL-01-19    | 2019-04-10 | 2019-03-27 |        83 |
| COL-01-20    | 2019-04-11 | 2019-03-28 |        83 |
| COL-01-21    | 2019-04-09 | 2019-03-29 |        80 |
| COL-01-22    | 2019-04-10 | 2019-03-30 |        80 |
| COL-01-23    | 2019-04-11 | 2019-03-31 |        80 |
| COL-01-24    | 2019-04-14 | 2019-04-01 |        13 |
| COL-01-25    | 2019-04-15 | 2019-04-02 |        13 |
| COL-01-26    | 2019-04-14 | 2019-04-03 |        11 |
| COL-01-27    | 2019-04-17 | 2019-04-04 |        13 |
| COL-01-28    | 2019-04-16 | 2019-04-05 |        11 |
| COL-01-29    | 2019-04-19 | 2019-04-06 |        13 |
| COL-01-30    | 2019-04-20 | 2019-04-07 |        13 |
| COL-01-31    | 2019-04-20 | 2019-04-08 |        12 |
| COL-01-32    | 2019-04-23 | 2019-04-09 |        14 |
```

Es una tabla de ejemplo que creé insertando los valores a través de CURDATE(), DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1  DAY), DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2  DAY), etc., con esta estructura:

```html
MariaDB [registro]> DESCRIBE batchinput;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+                                                                                               
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |                                                                                               
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+                                                                                               
| id             | int(11)     | NO   | UNI | NULL              | auto_increment              |                                                                                               
| batchnumber    | varchar(30) | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |                                                                                               
| L3beddate      | date        | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |                                                                                               
| L5enddate      | date        | NO   |     | NULL              |
```

Como se aprecia en la primera tabla, al comenzar a restar las fechas, los valores de "Ciclo" son correctos, pero cuando L5enddate tiene valores entre 2019-04-01 y 2019-04-11, los datos de ciclo no son correctos. Entiendo que está suponiendo que por ejemplo el lote COL-01-13 tiene fecha de L5enddate del 4 de febrero, cuando su fecha real es el 2 de abril. Para comprobar la lectura de la fecha, hice otra consulta:

```html
MariaDB [registro]> SELECT batchnumber, DATE_FORMAT(L5enddate, "%W %M %e %Y") AS L5, DATE_FORMAT(L3beddate, "%W %M %e %Y") AS L3, (L5enddate-L3beddate) as Ciclo FROM batchinput;
+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+
| batchnumber  | L5                      | L3                      | Ciclo     |
+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+
| COL-01-01    | Monday March 25 2019    | Saturday March 9 2019   |        16 |
| COL-01-02    | Thursday March 21 2019  | Sunday March 10 2019    |        11 |
| COL-01-03    | Thursday March 21 2019  | Monday March 11 2019    |        10 |
| COL-01-04    | Monday March 25 2019    | Tuesday March 12 2019   |        13 |
| COL-01-05    | Tuesday March 26 2019   | Wednesday March 13 2019 |        13 |
| COL-01-06    | Tuesday March 26 2019   | Thursday March 14 2019  |        12 |
| COL-01-07    | Thursday March 28 2019  | Friday March 15 2019    |        13 |
| COL-01-08    | Tuesday March 26 2019   | Saturday March 16 2019  |        10 |
| COL-01-09    | Wednesday March 27 2019 | Sunday March 17 2019    |        10 |
| COL-01-10    | Sunday March 31 2019    | Monday March 18 2019    |        13 |
| COL-01-11    | Monday April 1 2019     | Tuesday March 19 2019   |        82 |
| COL-01-12    | Tuesday April 2 2019    | Wednesday March 20 2019 |        82 |
| COL-01-13    | Tuesday April 2 2019    | Thursday March 21 2019  |        81 |
| COL-01-14    | Friday April 5 2019     | Friday March 22 2019    |        83 |
| COL-01-15    | Wednesday April 3 2019  | Saturday March 23 2019  |        80 |
| COL-01-16    | Thursday April 4 2019   | Sunday March 24 2019    |        80 |
| COL-01-17    | Sunday April 7 2019     | Monday March 25 2019    |        82 |
| COL-01-18    | Friday April 5 2019     | Tuesday March 26 2019   |        79 |
| COL-01-19    | Wednesday April 10 2019 | Wednesday March 27 2019 |        83 |
| COL-01-20    | Thursday April 11 2019  | Thursday March 28 2019  |        83 |
| COL-01-21    | Tuesday April 9 2019    | Friday March 29 2019    |        80 |
| COL-01-22    | Wednesday April 10 2019 | Saturday March 30 2019  |        80 |
| COL-01-23    | Thursday April 11 2019  | Sunday March 31 2019    |        80 |
| COL-01-24    | Sunday April 14 2019    | Monday April 1 2019     |        13 |
| COL-01-25    | Monday April 15 2019    | Tuesday April 2 2019    |        13 |
| COL-01-26    | Sunday April 14 2019    | Wednesday April 3 2019  |        11 |
| COL-01-27    | Wednesday April 17 2019 | Thursday April 4 2019   |        13 |
| COL-01-28    | Tuesday April 16 2019   | Friday April 5 2019     |        11 |
| COL-01-29    | Friday April 19 2019    | Saturday April 6 2019   |        13 |
| COL-01-30    | Saturday April 20 2019  | Sunday April 7 2019     |        13 |
| COL-01-31    | Saturday April 20 2019  | Monday April 8 2019     |        12 |
| COL-01-32    | Tuesday April 23 2019   | Tuesday April 9 2019    |        14 |
```

que viene a indicar que efectivamente, está leyendo la fecha del lote COL-01-13 como el 2 de abril, y debería restarla al 21 de marzo y obtener un valor de ciclo de 12 días.

¿Tendría que transformar las fechas antes de la resta? Quiero crear una GENERATED COLUMNS a partir de la resta, y así fue como detecté el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque a simple vista parece que la primera fecha la está interpretando al revés, no es cierto. Si analizas el caso del batch COL-01-11 la diferencia debería ser de 74 días, no de 82 en caso que estuviera interpretando la fecha como 4 de Enero.

El problema es la resta de fechas, no estas utilizando la función determinada para ello que es [DATEDIFF](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/datediff/). Lo que está sucediendo es que al usar el operador de resta mysql convierte 2019-04-01 y 2019-03-19 a los números 20190401 y 20190319 cuya resta, ¡efectivamente es 82!

Por ejemplo:

```
create table prueba_fecha(
  codigo int,
  fecha1 date,
  fecha2 date
  );

insert into prueba_fecha values (1, '2019/04/01', '2019/03/19');
```

Y si ejecutamos:

```
select codigo, fecha1, fecha2, DATEDIFF(fecha1,fecha2), fecha1-fecha2
from prueba_fecha
```

Obtenemos la siguiente información:

```
codigo  fecha1      fecha2      DATEDIFF(fecha1,fecha2)     fecha1-fecha2
1       2019-04-01  2019-03-19      13                          82
```

Puedes observar que **DATEDIFF** nos da el resultado correcto. Aquí esta el [ejemplo que realicé](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f10945e/1)